# REGEXP_SUBSTR to split delimited values

Tags: oracle, oracle-sql-developer, regular-expression

I have a field called `FREQUENCY` and it has values like `'10,0;30'`. How do I write a regular expression to get the result like this:

```
FREQUENCY 

10
0
30
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want a single row's value returned without the commas and semi-colons then the easiest way to accomplish this is with the [`REPLACE()` function](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/sqlrf/REPLACE.html#GUID-1A79BDDF-2D3B-4AD4-98E7-985B2E59DA6B) like this: `REPLACE(REPLACE(FREQUENCY, ',', ' '), ';', ' ') "FREQUENCY"`.

Answer (score 0):

As you have different delimiters, change them to one (e.g. semi-colon) and then split column to rows.

```
SQL> with test (freq) as
  2    (select '10,0;30' from dual)
  3  select regexp_substr(replace(freq, ',', ';'), '[^;]+', 1, level) freq
  4  from test
  5  connect by level <= regexp_count(replace(freq, ',', ';'), ';') + 1;

FREQ
-------
10
0
30

SQL>
```

Comment: Nope, @Vérace. Hit the "Edit" button under the question, you'll see that current info is misleading. My edit is pending as I don't have enough reputation. Feel free to approve it :)

Answer (score 0):

Similar to Littlefoot's answer, you can use `REGEXP_SUBSTR`, but instead of needing to replace all delimiters as a single delimiter, you can just split the strings by searching for repeating digits.

```sql
WITH d (freq) AS (SELECT '10,0;30' FROM DUAL)
    SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR (freq,
                          '\d+',
                          1,
                          LEVEL)    freq
      FROM d
CONNECT BY LEVEL <= REGEXP_COUNT (freq, '\d+');

   FREQ
_______
10
0
30
```